# Is it possible for MySQL to "auto-update" a field whenever changes are made in another, unrelated table?

Tags: mysql

Let's say that we have one table with a field called sales_total and another table with a bunch of sales entries. Let's also, for a moment, imagine that it is impractical to count the entries every time we want to see the total number of sales.

Is it possible to have MySQL automatically update the sales_total field every time the number of sales entries changes?

I know that you can do this by running another query via C#, PHP or whatever - I'm just curious whether MySQL (or some other database system) can do this within itself?

P.S. This is of course a pretty banal example - the ideal solution should be able to handle more complex operations (storing several rows as a string in a field, etc).

Comment: With a trigger, yes it should be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use mysql trigger...
trigger on update from the first table should have some queries to update the second table.

Comment: Yes, this seems EXACTLY what I'm looking for. Just one additional question - how complex can the triggered operation be?

Comment: As complex as you make it. However, avoid this. Triggers can lead to a lot of pain in complex systems- very hard to trace.

Comment: So, say, turning a lot of rows into a single string and storing it in a field is possible (JSON maybe?) ?

Comment: Its only hard to detect if you don't know its exist...   but its the best thing if you want to build you business on DB level.